# Android app with basic food and exercise logging per day

Tags: android, health, fitness

I ideally want an app for Android with less focus on calory counting, that simply logs what foods and exercise I've done that day and shows it in the same page.

Comment: I would still go with My Fitness Pal (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myfitnesspal.android&hl=en_GB)  Simply enter food and exercise and ignore the calories count at the bottom of the page.  It requires no extra effort, the food is clearly displayed, as is the exercise, with the bonus that if you ever change your mind, all of your calorific history is already there.

Answer (score 1):

[health-pie](https://www.mtatva.com/) The complete family health app for android user with all the option from

- Medication Reminders
- Health Information
- Vaccination Reminders
- Medical Records
- Vital Charts Tracking

Comment: Your answer does not address the question's requirements: logging foods and exercise.